# How do I programmatically delete forum comments in drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-comments

In my website I need to give a delete option for users to remove their own comment in a forum. I want to delete comments and update comment node statistics. Is there any Drupal functions available to delete comments?

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 7 there is [comment_delete_multiple()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.module/function/comment_delete_multiple/7) which invokes the hooks involved in the comments deletion, and updates the node statistics through [_comment_update_node_statistics()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.module/function/_comment_update_node_statistics/7). It requires an array of comment IDs.

In Drupal 6, there isn't an equivalent function, but you write the equivalent of the Drupal 7 function, considering that:

- Drupal 6 doesn't have functions to handle transactions
- In Drupal 6, the name of hooks invoked when deleting a comment are different
- Drupal 6 doesn't have entity fields
- Drupal 6 doesn't have any equivalent for `db_delete()` or `comment_load_multiple()`

Answer (score 0):

http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/trigger

Drupal trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Something like...

```
<?php

// you'll need to include /modules/comment/comment.admin.inc
module_load_include('inc', 'comment', 'comment.admin');

// I'm assuming you have access to the cid, the unique
// identifier for comments stored in the {comments} table
$comment = _comment_load($cid);
_comment_delete_thread($comment);
_comment_update_node_statistics($comment->nid);

?>
```

This solution is for Drupal 6 but you can borrow include files from the comment module and hijack their functions in other versions too.

I'm not sure if contrib modules extending the core forum functionality (like [Advanced Forum](http://drupal.org/project/advanced_forum)) provide an option without writing custom code, but you might want to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 7
Use the comment_delete()

```
<?php

    //Delete single comment
    $cid = 3917; //cid from `comment` table
    comment_delete($cid);

    //Delete multiple comments
    $cids = array(137421,137426,137427,137428,137429,137430,137431,137434,137450,137472);
    foreach ($cids as $cid) {
       comment_delete($cid);    
    }
```